# How to limit number of sections in minitoc using titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc, minitoc

Anyone know how to limit number of section titles, for example to 3 or 4, in one line minitoc using titletoc? So, in example bellow, sections starting with "Kolyvagin Classes" should be in the second line.

Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents*{csection}[0pt]
    {\centering\small\itshape}{}{}
    {}[\space\textbullet\space]

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{c}{1}{}

\section{Large Degree Isogenies}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\section{Cassels Pairing}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\section{The Hidden Root Problem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\section{Kolyvagin Classes}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\section{Pairing-Friendly Groups}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\parshape`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents*{csection}[0pt]
    {\centering\small\itshape\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-6em\relax}{}{}
    {}[\space\textbullet~]

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{c}{1}{}

\section{Large Degree Isogenies}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\section{Cassels Pairing}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\section{The Hidden Root Problem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\section{Kolyvagin Classes}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\section{Pairing-Friendly Groups}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also that I changed `\space\textbullet\space` to `\space\textbullet~` to guarantee that a bullet and its entry won't be separated by a line break.